# facebook invite friends to app and get id selected users

Tags: ios, facebook

I need invite facebook friends to my app and get selected facebook id.
I use this code

```
let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent();
            content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "https:// fb.me/571196839709216");
            FBSDKAppInviteDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self);
```

but after selected user and send I recv in delegate just "completed"...
How I can invite user and get your fb id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell which users are invited, you can barely tell they finished the process...

Comment: If I need invite friends and register foo on server I can do something?
For example if user invited from app so he will be get additional ability...

Comment: all you can do is on signup get the users friendlist and then if one of their friends signs up after then give additional ability